# c# DownloadFileAsync, doesn't work with absolute path

Tags: c#, path

```
string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) +
                                     "\\" + directores[directores.Length - 2] +
                                     "\\" + Path.GetFileName(url_img).Replace(" ", "_");
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url_img), path);
```

This code over doesn't work, the path seems to be good when i check it via MessageBox:

[image]

I have tried also with `@` symbol, but it neither works.

If I enter not a path but a name, e.g

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url_img), "test");
```

everything is ok. How can I solve this?

Forgot to add: If such path doesn't exist, I want to create it!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work". Are you getting any exception?

Comment: No, no exception, but also it doesn't save files.

Comment: Try with other path, i.e. `c:\test`; Offtopic: Use `Debug.Print` instead of MessageBox for diagnostic messages.

Comment: No exception means? Are you sure that the `Task` returned by `DownloadFileAsync` has `IsFaulted==false`?

Comment: Subscribe to the [`DownloadFileCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event and check the `Error`

Answer (score 2):

Whenever using async methods is your responsibility to check the result. For `DownloadFileAsync` the responsibility is to implement a [`DownloadFileCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted(v=vs.110).aspx). In the event, look at the [`Error`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.asynccompletedeventargs.error(v=vs.110).aspx), it will give you precious clues about *why* it failed.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution:

```
if (!Directory.Exists(directores[directores.Length - 2])) 
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directores[directores.Length - 2]);



string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) +
                                 "\\" + directores[directores.Length - 2] +
                                 "\\" + Path.GetFileName(url_img).Replace(" ", "_");
if (!Directory.Exists(directores[directores.Length - 2])) Directory.CreateDirectory(directores[directores.Length - 2]);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url_img), path);
```

Thanks for trying help.

So this function doesn't create folder if it doesn't exist, we have to create it before.